# commons-email HTML message problems

Tags: java, email, apache-commons-email

Hopefully just a quick one.

Essentially I am using apache commons email v1.3.3 and I am trying to send a HTML format email. I have followed their [user guide](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html) to do this however the email I am receiving is just not resolving to HTML in any client I view it in, all of which support HTML..

Here is the snippet of code essentially sending it:

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setTo(getRecipients(recipients));
    email.setHtmlMsg(htmlMsg);
    email.setTextMsg(alternativeMsg);
    try {
        this.mailServer.send(email);
    }
    catch (EmailException e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error occurred sending email. ", e);
    }
```

Now lets say the html is this:

`<html>some text in html <p> blah blah blah </html>`

I am just receiving plain text content as is above.

Could someone please highlight what I am missing?

Thanks,

Edit:

Having made use of the debug feature, I can see the content-type remains plain/text. To resolve my issue I have instead done this:

`email.setContent(htmlMsg, EmailConstants.TEXT_HTML);`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the commons-email library for quite some time. I think, you set the message using the `setMsg()` method instead of `setHtmlMsg()`. Rewrite the code as below, and it should work fine.

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setTo(getRecipients(recipients));
    email.setMsg(htmlMsg);

    try {
        this.mailServer.send(email);
    }
    catch (EmailException e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error occurred sending email. ", e);
    }
```

There is another problem that I faced with this HTML email.  The library adds a `<pre>` tag to our message, and that makes the styles and alignments a bit odd.  I had to override the `setMsg()` to overcome this problem.

Comment: That won't make a difference. The only difference is that setMsg() implicitly wraps your message with   `<html><body><pre>` tags.